# setting the field in the JSON body to contents in a file while making a Http post call in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, https, certificate, http-post, csr

I am trying to install a certificate issued by a digicert CA. First i am generating the CSR (Certificate Signing request) using the Powershell Script. I am putting the generated CSR in a txt file and removing all the line breaks, spaces and carriage returns. I am using the following script to do that:

```
$CSR > C:\Scripts\CSR.txt
$path = "C:\Scripts\CSR.txt"
(Get-Content $path -Raw).Replace("`r`n","") | Set-Content $path -Force
(Get-Content $path -Raw).Replace(" ","") | Set-Content $path -Force
(Get-Content $path -Raw).Replace("`r`n","") | Set-Content $path -Force -NoNewline
```

After that i want to make a http post call to digiCert to get the Certificate Id. For that I am Using the following script:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12, tls11, tls"
$body = @"
{
 "profile_name": "XXX",
 "common_name": "XX",
 "additional_dns_names": [
   "XX",
   "XX"
 ],
 "csr":$CSRWithNoCRLF,

 "signature_hash": "sha256",
 "validity": {
   "months": 36
 },
 "organization": {
   "name": "XXX",
   "units": [

   ]
 }
}
"@


$header = @{
 "Accept"="application/json"
 "KEY"="XXXX"
 "Content-Type"="application/json"
} 

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.digicert.comXXXX" -Method Post -Body $body -Headers $header 
$Content = $response.Content
```

For the csr field in the body of the JSON i want to directly copy the contents of C:\Scripts\CSR.txt file. I tried following approach but it is not working.

```
$CSRWithNoCRLF = Get-Content $path
```

And use $CSRWithNoCRLF as the value for the csr. But the Get-Content is adding  line breaks and carriage returns and malforming the CSR value. So this is not Working. Any Idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: How does your [code signing request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request) look like? Is it b64 encoded? Redirecting to a file would result in UTF16 not UTF8.

Comment: Can you show us an example of `C:\Scripts\CSR.txt` and print `$CSRWithNoCRLF` ? Also is `$CSRWithNoCRLF` is declared somewhere else in your script ?

Comment: @Fourat This is how my CSR.txt looks like:


-----BEGINNEWCERTIFICATEREQUEST-----XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGjNXLUg4NUdHUDIuY2xvdWQud2VpcgwMV2VpclwxMjg5NjNxDAtjZXJ0cmVxLmV4ZTBdBgkqhkiG9w0BCQ4xUDBOMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIFoDAdBgNVHSUEFjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAQYIKwYBBQUHAwIwHQYDVR0OBBYEFAwOrH9r/raqCI22h61CZnbAkiPPMHIGCisGAQQBgjcNAgIxZDBiAgEBHloATQBpAGMAcgBvAHMAbwBmAHQAIABSAFMAQQAZABlAHIDAQAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQuVScSE6x1wUBrrOE5UWlS9P6pW=-----ENDNEWCERTIFICATEREQUEST-----

Comment: @Fourat I have not declared $CSRWithNoCRLF somewhere else in my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get-Content is adding line breaks

Several ways, each is a complete solution:

```
$CSRWithNoCRLF = Get-Content $path -Raw     # requires PSv3+

Get-Content $path | Out-String

(Get-Content $path) -join "`n"       # use "`r`n" for Windows-style line-endings
```

> Edit

Examine what you are sending. Try this:

```
[regex]::Escape($Body)
```

If you used `(Get-Content $path) -join "`n"` then you will not have \r\n line endings in the CSR part. However, why are you handcrafting JSON? If you do that on a windows box, you'll have Windows line endings in your JSON string.

Try this:

```
$Body = [pscustomobject]@{
    profile_name = "XXX"
    common_name = "XX"
    additional_dns_names = @(
        "XX",
        "XX"
    )
    csr = (Get-Content $Path) -join "`n"
    signature_hash = "sha256"
    validity = [pscustomobject]@{
        months = 36
    }
    organization = [pscustomobject]@{
        name = "XXX"
        units = @()
    }

} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

Note that I'm using `Compress`.

```
> [regex]::Escape($Body) -match '\\r'
False
```

Give that a go.

Comment: I tried all the three methods you mentioned. In every approach its adding CRLF in the end after each line and its not working.

Comment: If you explicitly join with \n and not \r\n then it definitely will not add CR to your `$CSRWithNoCRLF` variable. Perhaps your API doesn't like the line endings in your JSON-formatted body? See my edit for how to let the builtin JSON serialiser format that for you. Also, try not sending through JSON and just letting `Invoke-WebRequest` serialise it for you.

Comment: Thanks, this is working. As you said handcrafting the JSON was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$CSRWithNoCRLF = (Get-Content $path -Raw).Replace("`r`n","").Replace(" ","")
$body = @"
{
 "profile_name": "XXX",
 "common_name": "XX",
 "additional_dns_names": [
   "XX",
   "XX"
 ],
 "csr":"$CSRWithNoCRLF",

 "signature_hash": "sha256",
 "validity": {
   "months": 36
 },
 "organization": {
   "name": "XXX",
   "units": [

   ]
 }
}
"@
$header = @{
 "Accept"="application/json"
 "KEY"="XXXX"
 "Content-Type"="application/json"
} 

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.digicert.comXXXX" -Method Post -Body $body -Headers $header 
$Content = $response.Content
```

I don't see the need to save back the certificate to the file after modifying it.

Comment: I tried this. still not working. Get-Content is adding line breaks after each line.

Comment: What's your Powershell version ? I tried it on PS 5.1.16299.1004 and it works fine. `Get-Content $path -Raw` returns the line breaks but I replace all line breaks and white spaces with `.Replace("`r`n","").Replace(" ","")` so logically the `$CSRWithNoCRLF` string variable shouldn't have any line breaks or white spaces. Please create a new script with my code and test it.